# How to tie Google Contacts API access token to one of *my* app’s users?

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, privacy, google-contacts-api

We (that is, our app — we’ll call it FooMaker) have entirely client-side code that downloads a user’s contacts from Google, if they authorize our app to do so.

Now… if our user Kelly logs out of FooMaker, and another user Rob logs in to FooMaker, then (before the token expires) Rob will actually have access to all of Kelly’s contacts. (Technically, this is true not just in our app, but also if Rob went to google.com.)

Still, it feels weird — is this a problem other developers look out for? How do you deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

The access token is managed by your application. When user logs out of your application, the access token should be removed from your application -- from memory, preference file or database -- depends how your application stores it.

Comment: We don’t store it anywhere — it’s a client-side Google cookie, and then javascript running on our page that sends us the data in question